# Have a JSON need to highlight the answers from ng-repeat that match the ones in JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, styles, matching

Ok i have a JSON file that stores the answers the user has already answered, next i have an ng-repeat that prints all the questions and all the possible answers to those questions......what i need is to load the JSON file and watch the ng-repeat for those values and as they come up... apply a different css class to that one answer (for example change the color of the text)....

I have 3 sections and the code bellow sorts my questions into those sections

```
<ul style='display: inline-block' ng-repeat="(key, value) in q.flow" ng-if="q.sectionName == 'SectionName'">
<li>{{label(key)}}</li>
</ul>

<ul style='display: inline-block' ng-repeat="(key, value) in q.flow" ng-if="q.sectionName == 'SectionName2'">
<li>{{label(key)}}</li>
</ul>

<ul style='display: inline-block' ng-repeat="(key, value) in q.flow" ng-if="q.sectionName == 'SectionName3'">
<li>{{label(key)}}</li>
</ul>
```

JSON is loaded into a $scope.useranswersJson...

Comment: Do you have an example of the json? Or any of the actual Angular code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of info - but it looks like you're expecting to use something like ng-class. Here's how it works:

```
<ul style='display: inline-block' ng-class="{highlight: value === 'blah'}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in q.flow" ng-if="q.sectionName == 'SectionName'">
<li>{{label(key)}}</li>
</ul>
```

So when the the `value` becomes the one you're watching for (or whatever other condition you're expecting to highlight for) - the class of `highlight` will automatically be added. When that condition is false, it is removed.

**EDIT**

You also probably mean to iterate over `<li>` elements, not `<ul>`:

```
<ul style='display: inline-block' ng-if="q.sectionName == 'SectionName'">
<li ng-class="{highlight: value === 'blah'}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in q.flow">{{label(key)}}</li>
</ul>
```